# Load PDF in Vaadin from Resource

Tags: pdf, vaadin7

I designed a Document Viewer in Vaadin that displays PDF files to the user. I successfully added the PDF to the viewer by specifying the system path. The problem is when I run the Viewer in a remote system, the PDF isn't displayed. So is there any way to load the PDF using the resource like we load the images.
Here is my code:

```
File pdfFile = new java.io.File ("D:/WorkFiles/PDF Books/newsletter.pdf");
```

The pdf is loading only from the local system. I have tried adding the pdf in the `themes` folder, but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That kind of Resource do you use?

Comment: Hi @HenriKerola. I tried using ThemeResource, but it didn't work. So I used the FileResource for loading the PDF. But it is loading only from the system specific location not from the server or from URL.

Answer (score 0):

What about the https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/StreamResource.html. You can use this for on demand generated PDF files.